# publish image in facebook users wall from webos

Tags: webos, palm-pre

in my application i select one image from photos and then press submit button selected image should publish in facebook user wall with some message.any idea

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aswan, there is a simple way to do this by leveraging Palm's facebook application.  Essentially your app would be making a service request to the facebook app which would then pop-up and ask the user to confirm a status update or photo post.  More info [here](https://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=5677).

If you don't use this solution, you will need to craft your own AJAX requests to authenticate with Facebook and make whatever updates you desire.

Which solution are you interested in?  Also are you using the Ares IDE or Eclipse?

Comment: i am using eclipse ide is good or not developing palm application eclipse